# Remotipart file upload giving NaN as response code

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, remotipart

I am using remotipart to upload a file with ajax in my rails app. I am using the jquery-ujs Ajax "global" events `ajax:success` and `ajax:error` in my javascript to trigger code on success or failure. The problem is that the error callback is always firing and never the success.

I can see in the developer tools network tab that the request is returning a 200 OK status.

This is my form where the remote upload is triggered.

```
= form_tag({ action: 'import' }, html: { multipart: true },  class: 'csv_import_form', remote: true, data: { type: :json }) do
```

My controller processes the request as json and renders a json response:

```
def import
  render json: { some: 'sample json' }
end
```

and this is what the response body looks like as seen in developer tools:

```
<textarea data-type="application/json" data-status="200" data-statusText="OK">{"some":"sample json"}</textarea>
```

Remotipart wraps the response in a text area. Notice that it does include `data-status="200"`

Here is the javascript:

```
$(function() {

  $(document).on("ajax:success", ".csv_import_form", function(event, data, status, xhr)  {

    // does not get here

  }).on("ajax:error", ".csv_import_form", function(event, xhr, status, error) {
      console.log("status code: " + xhr.status);
      console.log("json: " + xhr.responseText);
      console.log("status text: " + xhr.statusText);
      console.log("status: " + status);
      console.log("error: " + error);
  });
});
```

This is what I see output in the console:

```
status code: NaN
json: {"some":"sample json"}
status text: OK
status: OK
error: OK
```

It seems the actual Textarea response is not being properly parsed. Even though it has data-status="200", it is being parsed as a NaN and thus invoking the error callback.

Has anyone seen this?

Using:

```
rails 4.0.13
remotipart 1.2.1
jquery 1.7.2
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried wrapping everything in document(ready) function?

Comment: Yes, should have mentioned, I am setting up those event handlers inside of a document(ready) function. Thanks for the suggestion! Edited the original question to show that.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that even though I upgraded the `remotipart gem` to the latest version (`1.2.1` at this time), the included javascript files had gotten out of date.

To fix I deleted:

```
app/assets/javascripts/jquery.remotipart.js
```

and

```
app/assets/javascripts/jquery.iframe-transport.js
```

and instead added

```
//= require jquery.remotipart
```

to my `application.js` file, and then it worked as expected.